# jenkins: temporarily git checkout other branch causes incorrect hash of triggering commit

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job that checks out a different branch than the one that triggered the job, to do some git-related computations, and then proceeds with the main git checkout:

```
// find most recent tag on master branch:
git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'bitbucket', poll: false, url: 'git@bitbucket.org:ORG_NAME/REPO.git'
tag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git describe --abbrev=0 --tags' ).trim()
...

// now build the actual commit that triggered this job
scmVars = checkout(scm)
println scmVars.GIT_COMMIT // ***
docker build ...
```

The `checkout(scm)` call shows output that indicates the correct commit is checked out, ie the one that triggered the job. However the `scmVars.GIT_COMMIT` is the git commit hash of the FIRST checkout, ie of the master branch. This is so weird! I thought the whole point of `checkout()` returning a map was for the map to have the GIT checkout properties like commit hash etc related to what was just checked out!

Any enlightenment as to why this is happening, and how to fix, would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I found an acceptable workaround (ie not really a hack) but still would be nice to understand why `checkout(scm)` not working as expected. The workaround is to do the `checkout(scm)` first, and do the second git checkout in a `dir(SOME_FOLDER_NAME)` block:

```
// now build the actual commit that triggered this job
scmVars = checkout(scm)
println scmVars.GIT_COMMIT // ***

// find most recent tag on master branch:
dir() {
    git changelog: false, credentialsId: 'bitbucket', poll: false, url: 'git@bitbucket.org:ORG_NAME/REPO.git'
    tag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git describe --abbrev=0 --tags' ).trim()
    ...
}

sh 'git reflog'
docker build ...
```

The git reflog after the dir shows that the current commit is the one that triggered the build, not the one used in the `git changelog:...`.

Interestingly, even *with* the `dir()` around that master checkout, putthing the `scmVars = checkout(scm)` after it still returns wrong GIT values for 1st checkout!!